# How to find the biggest value for from nested array Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, multidimensional-array

I am pretty new to javascript .I am little bit confused that how to find  biggest value for particular array objects from nested array.For example

If we have a Huge array like this  ...

```
 [ 
    .....
     [ { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
            { id: 1, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

          [ { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
            { id: 1, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

          [ { id: 0, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
            { id: 1, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

          [ { id: 0, value: 21, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
            { id: 1, value: 11, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

          [ { id: 0, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
            { id: 1, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

          [ { id: 0, value: 11, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
            { id: 1, value: 21, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ] 
....
    ]
```

How to find biggest value in each array object value by with the help of valueObject inside nested array.
Sorry I am not literally good at exaplaining my question 
But take a look at this example...

```
[ 
        .....
             //Higest value of the value Object in below Array Object is 19
            [ 
            { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
                { id: 1, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } 
            ],
          //Higest value of the value Object in below Array Object is 18
              [ 
                { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
                { id: 1, value: 18, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } 
             ],
          //Higest value of the value Object in below Array Object is 21
              [ 
                { id: 0, value: 21, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
                { id: 1, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' }
              ],


    ....
        ]
```

My result should like this
just print the lowest array Objects like this

```
//Higest value of the value Object in below Array Object is 18
                  [ 
                    { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
                    { id: 1, value: 18, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } 
                 ],
 //Higest value of the value Object in below Array Object is19
                [ 
                { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
                    { id: 1, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } 
                ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the library Lodash to get it.

It's available at: https://lodash.com

Here is an example of how you can do it with Loadash:

First, let's assume you data structure as:

```
var myArray = [ 
      [ { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
            { id: 1, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

      [ { id: 0, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
        { id: 1, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

      [ { id: 0, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
        { id: 1, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

      [ { id: 0, value: 21, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
        { id: 1, value: 11, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

      [ { id: 0, value: 19, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
        { id: 1, value: 13, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ],

      [ { id: 0, value: 11, jobs: [Object], name: 'M1' },
        { id: 1, value: 21, jobs: [Object], name: 'M2' } ] 
];
```

You can use Loadash to find the greater value for each sub-array:

```
_.forEach(myArray, function(subArray) {
    var subArrayValues = _.map(subArray, function (o) { 
        return o.value;
    });

    var subArrayMaxValue = _.max(subArrayValues);
    var subArrayMinValue = _.min(subArrayValues);

    console.log("Higest value of the value Object in below Array Object is " + subArrayMaxValue);
    console.log("Lowest value of the value Object in below Array Object is " + subArrayMinValue);
    console.log(subArray);
});
```